# In the python version of Google App Engine, how do I find the quartile values of a model with an index on a specific property?

Tags: google-app-engine, median

In Google App Engine I have a model with 10K entities with an index on the property foo. What is the most efficient way to find the 1st quartile, 2nd quartile (the median), and the 3rd quartile entities? I can fetch the sorted list of keys and find the three quartile keys programmatically, but downloading all the keys won't scale. What is the more elegant approach?

```
sortedValues = MyModel.all(keys_only=True).order('foo').fetch(limit=10000)
```

Comment: You say it won't scale because the entities could be more than 10K? Are you storing the entities with a custom `key_name`?

Comment: No. No custom key name. It seems like the best approach may be to fetch the keys_only count of all the entities for my query and then fetch the three entities at the int offsets limit*0.25, limit*0.5, and limit*0.75 for my ordered query. That would be 4 total fetches to find the 3 quartile values. The count may be my only non-scaling part and a counter might help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `.fetch(2500,limit=1)`, `.fetch(5000,limit=1)`, and `.fetch(7500,limit=1)`?  The first argument corresponds to the offset.

The documentation reads the following, however, so this approach won't afford you `O(1)` performance.

```
Note: The query has performance characteristics that correspond linearly with the offset amount plus the limit amount.
```

From [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Since quartiles are defined in terms of entity ordering, there's unfortunately no way to determine them other than iterating over them. As cheeken points out, you can speed things up a little by not fetching the intermediate results by using an offset argument.